# Interceptor.intercept Is Not A Function

Tags: angular, angular5

I've been trying to implement an application-wide interceptor, however, I keep seeing the following error:

```
TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function
```

After much debugging, I realized the reason why it's happening is because I have a service that is being called from a child component. When I use the custom interceptor from the app.component, everything works fine, but if I use it from a child component, I get that error. I am at a loss. Here is a code sample. I set it up in mostly the same way my app is set up:

https://angular-rbbkvv.stackblitz.io/test/index (there's no validation; no POST is made so data is collected)

As you can see, I am displaying the error, which is the error posted above. On top of that, if you follow the network tab, you will not see the POST being made.

I have spent days on this issue, and I'm at a loss. I really hope I am doing something very simple wrong.

I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `useValue` in the following

```
providers: [
  { 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useValue: MyHttpInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Replace it with `useClass` and it should work

Comment: Thank you SO much. That was exactly what it was. I appreciate your help, and the little tidbit of info for future reference!